# Is it okay to write $f(x)^2$?

Tags: notation

As far as I understand we write $\cos^2 x$ just to not mix up $(\cos x)^2$ with $\cos(x^2)$. But it is difficult to associate $f(x)^2$ with anything else but $(f(x))^2$. Is it correct to use such a notation?

Comment: Use as $\cos^{2}\left(x\right)$. Use $\large\tt always$ $\left(~~\right)$ in a function call. In this place, that is always an obvious mistake.

Comment: Opionions on notation differ (and some people have very strong opinions about certains points of notation). For what it's worth, I personally consider $f(x)^2$ correct.

Comment: It's unambiguous and it's even preferable to $f^2(x)$ which could mean $f(f(x))$ (If $f:X\to X$ of course).

Comment: I agree, it is OK to write $f(x)^2$, meaning $(f(x))^2$.  But don't go so far as to claim those using other notation are *wrong*.

Comment: @faleichik : Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

by convention $$\cos^2x=(\cos x)^2$$
if
$$f^2(x)=f(f(x))$$
then must be $$\cos^2x=\cos(\cos x)$$
in general $$(\cos x)^2\neq\cos(\cos x)$$
Evidently using such notation is not correct but we use.